# Is there a way to change the radio button to an image?

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, radio-button, svelte

As the title expresses, I wish to turn a radio button `<input type="radio">` into an image, while still having the function of selecting it, changing the image. Here is an example (The code is in Svelte but its pretty much vanilla html)

```html
    <h2>Select Country to continue</h2>
    <form class="white" action="" on:submit={countrysubmit} bind:this={form}>
    <label for="US">
    <input type="radio" name="US" value="US">
    </label>
    </form>
    </main>
<style></style>
```

I want the US radio button thing to be an image, that can change while being selected and also have the selection be visible via JS (via `.forEach`, looping to find the selected element).

Comment: jmargolisvt No, because I want the whole radio button to be the image, not the radio button to be inside the image,

Comment: @SUPA: You clearly have not read the answers of the question fully. That is exactly what that question is about. It says so right in the title.

Comment: It's not about the question, it's about the solutions. They only work in a certain spot inside the image

Comment: You just have to wrap the radio and the image in a `label` and hide the radio button, like the accepted answer explains.